# Problems with JAXB marshalling lists of non-annotated objects

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I've got a bit of an issue with unmarshalling a list of closed objects using JAXB (closed in the sense that I cannot add JAXB annotation) . Basically, my XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
        <!-- SNIP! -->
    </rdf:RDF>
    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
        <!-- SNIP! -->
    </rdf:RDF>
</document>
```

And my Document class is:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "document", namespace = Namespace.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Document {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ModelAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name = "RDF", namespace = Namespace.RDF_NAMESPACE)
    private List<Model> models;
    ....
```

Where Model is a class from a framework that I cannot add JAXB annotations to, hence the adaptor.

The implementation of ModelAdapter is as follows:

```
public class ModelUnmarshalAdapter extends ModelAdapter<Object, Model> {

    @Override
    public Model unmarshal(final Object v) throws Exception {
        // Turn incoming Node into a Model object
        Model model = convert(v);
        return model;
    }
    ....
}
```

When I unmarshal the XML I'm finding ModelUnmarshalAdapter.unmarshal() is being called twice as expected (due to the 2 RDF elements in the XML), but the Document instance models property is always null. It's like it doesn't instantiate the necessary list instance.

Any ideas would be greatly appreceiated.

Thanks

Nick

Comment: I don't quite believe the inheritance structure of `XmlAdapter<?,?>`, `ModelAdapter<Object, Model>`, which is missing but set as `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` and `ModelUnmarshalAdapter`, which (as you say) is being called via `unmarshal`. A full set of java code reproducing the error is required here - or else it's all guesswork,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error it turns out the solution was to subclass the closed object concrete class (in my case ModelCom, which implements the Model interface) and add the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter to that

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ModelAdapter.class)
public class MyModel extends ModelCom {

    public Model(Graph base) {
        super(base);
    }

    public Model(Graph base, Personality<RDFNode> personality) {
        super(base, personality);
    }

}
```

The Document class is now simply

```
public class Document {

   @XmlElement(name = "RDF", namespace = Namespace.RDF_NAMESPACE)
   private List<MyModel> models;
```